# What is the right way to proceed when your answer was deleted by a moderator, and the question is on hold

Tags: discussion

I responded to this question:

[Is creationism falsifiable?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/37198/is-creationism-falsifiable)

The question itself is now on hold as off-topic, and my answer was deleted by a moderator as being unresponsive to the question.  My question here is what to do next?

In my own opinion, the first paragraph of my response was responsive to the question, but I wandered off into other topics in the remaining paragraphs. So I deleted all but the first paragraph, and added a second paragraph that, I think, continues the thought in the first paragraph.  Now what?  I can't undelete the answer, even though the undelete button is not grayed out (that seems like a bug).

so what I'm going to do, for now, is just wait to see what happens to the question itself.  If the question gets deleted, I presume all the answers get deleted with it.
If the question gets rehabilitiated, perhaps after revision, then I'm going to want to get my revised answer considered for rehabilitation.  Unless I hear something different in the responses to this question.

Comment: Looks like the question will almost certainly not be reopened: David Stratton said "I don't see a way to salvage this so that it's actually within the site guidelines" and the OP of the question implied he's satisfied with what he's learned and doesn't intend to further pursue the question. Closed questions aren't supposed to have been answered in the first place, so I wouldn't worry about what to do.

Comment: If you can think of a good way to reword the question in a way which fits the site guidelines while still honoring the original intent, then have at it...  Propose an edit.  If others agree, the edit will get accepted and then there's a good chance that the question might be reopened.

Comment: Thanks, but I'll leave that to others.

Comment: If this question: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/37251/have-creationists-advanced-any-particular-theories-of-origin-that-they-claim-are is regarded as on-topic, then perhaps some of your material will be relevant there.

Comment: The question looks good.  I have no answer, but I look forward to reading some.

Answer (score 8):

You're welcome to ask about it on meta. That's one of the best moves you can make if you feel like it was *wrongfully* deleted.

More importantly though, is the potential fate of this question and what you decide to do with your answer because of it.

As the comments alluded to, the odds of this question getting reopened are abysmal. It's a hard question to get on topic here, and the OP doesn't seem to care about reforming it to fit our tight standards on something like this (he feels like he has an answer already).

However, that *doesn't* mean you might not want to improve your answer and get it undeleted. You can still earn reputation on closed question answers, and there is no reason to believe that question will be deleted at some point in the near future (to keep any rep you earn, your post only has to stick around for 90 days.

So basically, if you have something to contribute you *can* edit your deleted post and flag it for undeletion.

As to whether or not we do that, will of course depend on the quality of your edits and how much we feel it adds value (and yes, the bar will be much higher because the question is already closed).

Generally though, I'd recommend spending your time and efforts somewhere else, if you *really* care about answering this particular question well, you might consider a more tightly focused version of the question to which you provide a self answer.

Comment: Sounds right.  The cost of foregone opportunity comes to the surface.